# Class Selenium in web UI get calling everytime I submit

Tags: python, selenium

I have made whatsappbot from terminal with python so I want to make UI from web but every time the **html form post** it's always open new **chromeWebdriver** because I declare the WhatsappBot(), how can I only call the class once and when html do post it's only call the method from class but not open the web driver

```
post = form.getvalue('postx') if form.getvalue('postx') else ''
arg1 = form.getvalue('arg1') if form.getvalue('arg1') else ''
arg2 = form.getvalue('arg2') if form.getvalue('arg2') else ''

whatsapp = WhatsappBot.WhatsappBot()
whatsapp.openWhatsAppWeb()

if arg2 != '':
    whatsapp.setPenerima(arg1)
    whatsapp.kirimPesan(arg2)

print("""
    <html>
<head>
    <title>WhatsApp Bot</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h2><b>Petunjuk Penggunaan:</b></h2>
        <p>1. Scan QR Code pada Whatsapp web<br />
            2. Pilih nama penerima, atau centang semua kontak jika pesan boardcast<br />
            3. Masukkan Pesan yang akan dikirim<br />
            4. Klik tombol " Kirim " untuk mengirim pesan<br />
            """+arg1+"""
        </p>
    </div>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
       <div class="formPost">
        .....
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i not sure but singleton pattern may help

```
from singleton_decorator import singleton

@singleton
class SingletonWhatsappBot(WhatsappBot.WhatsappBot):
    pass
```